# Disk price IDs for Paris 01 doesn't exist

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am retrieving price IDs for performance storage in the PAR01 data center, using this request:

```
GET /rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices.json?objectMask=mask[id,categories,locationGroupId,item]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"performance_storage_space"}},"locationGroupId":{"operation":"543"},"item":{"keyName":{"operation":"$=GBs"}}}}
```

If I use locationGroupID 505 (the OSL01 data center) it works, but for PAR01 nothing is returned. I can't believe that performance block storage isn't available for that data center, so I assume I've made a mistake.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To find the prices for a particular data center, we can use locations instead of the locationGroupID:

```
GET .../SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices.json?objectMask=mask[id,categories,item,pricingLocationGroup[locations[id,name,longName]]]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"performance_storage_space"}},"pricingLocationGroup":{"locations":{"name":{"operation":"par01"}}},"item":{"keyName":{"operation":"$=GBs"}}}}
```